# how to test your react toolkit query with console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtk-query

i am writing my first rtk query and i want to test if my query is working or not what is the best solution for testing my query in console tab

```js
export const search = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'search',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: myURL }),
  tagTypes: ['search'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getSearch: builder.mutation<searchDataRes, string>({
      query: ({ keyword }: any) => ({ url: /Post, method: 'GET' })
    })
  }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Redux Devtools and look at those - you will be able to observe pretty much everything there. Also, take a look at your network tab.

Comment: if i dont want to use redux devtools how can i console.log in this search constant

Comment: You can write console.log left and right and maybe get some information out of it, but you really just should use the tools made for the purpose. The Redux Devtools even come with an RTK Query inspector. `console.log` should always be your last debug tool if there is no tool made for the purpose - not your first.

Comment: thanks for your help i found the log monitor